# check all checkbox with extra ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [1,2,3,4];
  $scope.results = {};
  $scope.showButton = function () {
    for (var key in $scope.results) {
      if ($scope.results[key]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
    <input value="{{d}}" type="checkbox"/>
     check this to check all checkbox and show the button
    <br><br>
    
    <li ng-repeat="d in data"><input ng-model="results[$index]" value="{{d}}" type="checkbox"/>{{$index}}</li>
    <button ng-show="showButton()">Submit</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

My code above bind each of the checkbox and show the save button if any of them got checked, but now I having problem implementing the main checkbox, which will check all of the checkbox and show the button.

http://plnkr.co/edit/goVQtYxjgo8fA15oSGuy?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8upoqfObrVvRoLxN2n4?p=preview).

Add a new checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="toggleCheckAll()" ng-model="allChecked" />
check this to check all checkbox and show the button
```

Everytime you check/uncheck this chechbox, the function `toggleCheckall` will be invoked. In the controller:

```
$scope.allChecked = false;
$scope.toggleCheckAll = function () {
    for (var key in $scope.results) {
        $scope.results[key] = $scope.allChecked;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Joy, your solution has limitation, u declared $scope.result has static object first, but in my case it's dynamic, imagine it's data from a table.

Comment: I am just lazy... Use some `for` loop to do the initialization.

Comment: can you make a change? this might be useful for others in the future.

Comment: Well. I believe you can make it as well. But I updated the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8upoqfObrVvRoLxN2n4?p=preview)